# Writing a function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have been tasked with writing a program in R that defines a function, y, and values `a = 1`, `b =2`, and `e = normal distribution`. This program is then to regress y on x, and extract the coefficient as a new variable.
So far, I have written down:

```
Q3Data <- function(a = 1, b = 2, nPoints = 1000) {
x <- runif(nPoints);
y <- a + b * x + rnorm(nPoints, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  return(data.frame(x = x, y = y));
}
```

But I am unsure how to continue. As far as I understand, I am meant to include commands to carry out the requested tasks before the "}" at the end of the code, but I am unsure how to continue. I know how to run the regression as a separate step, but not as a "continuous" string of code.

Comment: Can you show the code you know of how to run the regression as a separate step?

Comment: @Gregor What I do then is:

df <- Q3Data();
head(df);

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df);
summary(fit);

Comment: Without telling you to do your homework, I would consider assigning your dataframe to a new object within your function.  Then, look up `?lm` if you have any question on how to fit a regression.  Once you've fit a model (say, mod), look at `str(summary(mod))` to see what the structure is of your model results and that should make it clear how to extract the information you want.

Comment: So, instead of `return(data.frame(...))` do `df <- data.frame(...)`, and then continue... (you can probably skip the `head(df)` inside your function).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something like what you're looking for? It calculates the linear model regression line and returns the line coefficient.

```
Q3Data <- function(a = 1, b = 2, nPoints = 1000) {
    x <- runif(nPoints)
    y <- a + b * x + rnorm(nPoints, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    fit <- lm(y ~ x)
    fit$coef[2]
}
```

No need to use the `return` statement in R functions. The result from the last executed command is returned from the function.